# Can TCP seq number increment after sending a FIN?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I have an embedded device connecting to a server (on AWS Application ELB if that matters). Both the server and the client are instructed to close the connection after one request. I noticed that the client took a long time to close the connection even after receiving back the HTTP response from the server. I know it uses a low-powered network with high latency but I still wanted to check if there was something else going on, so I took a tcp dump from both sides.

The screenshot shows the trace from client side. Concentrating at the connection close sequence:

- At packet 13 the client sends an empty FIN packet. There is high network latency so it doesn't get immediately the response back but a retransmission instead (packet 14).
- The client sends another FIN (packet 15) with incremented seq **(!!!)**.
- It happens again at packet 17 with further incremented seq **(!!!)**.

If I understand correctly the TCP state machine this is not a valid behavior. If packet 15 and 17 were retransmissions, they should have been sent with the same exact numbers. In fact, the server never acknowledges the incremented seq numbers.

[image: Client packet dump wireshark]

If necessary I can provide also a screenshot of the dump from server side, but it just shows the same packets in a different order, there is no packet loss.

Note: packet 16 shows relative seq num = 1 but the absolute raw value is correct and the same as packet 14.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is normal behavior. Yes, seq numbers do increment after initiating a FIN.

See the following question for details: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/47132

And here is the original RFC in case the above link ever breaks in the future: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5

Answer (score 1):

As @user3629081 indicated, `Sequence Number` value increases after every  `FIN` (and also after every `SYN`) - excluding the cases of `TCP` retransmissions. This results directly from the definitions of these control flags in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#page-79 (GLOSSARY):

> **FIN**
>
> A control bit (finis) **occupying one sequence** number, which indicates that the sender will send no more data or control occupying sequence space.

> **SYN**
>
> A control bit in the incoming segment, **occupying one sequence number**, used at the initiation of a connection, to indicate where the sequence numbering will start.

Your case (as well as normal connection termination, as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5) is a direct consequence of the definitions quoted above. Namely, `TCP` segments `15`, `17` are not `TCP` retransmissions (since `15` is just a another `TCP.FIN` segment and `17` is `TCP.DUP-ACK`) and therefore after these frames the `Sequence Number` is being increased. On the other hand, `TCP` segment `14` is a `TCP` retransmission (of `11`), and therefore it has the same `Sequence Number` as `11`.